# YouTube api v3 Invalid Credentials access token

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, afnetworking, google-signin

I am getting 401 Invalid Credentials error trying to use the Youtube API in the OAuth 2.0.

I used google sign in sdk and get access_token with params:

```
    GIDSignIn *sharedSignIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];

sharedSignIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = NO;

sharedSignIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
                       @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
                       @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
                      // @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
                       nil];

[sharedSignIn signIn];
```

Than I used AFNetworking library for GET request

```
- (void) getInformationWithParams: (NSDictionary *) params
                       method: (NSString *) method
                    onSuccess: (void(^)(NSDictionary *responseObject)) success
                    onFailure: (void (^) (NSError *error)) failure {

[self.requestOperationManager GET:method
                       parameters:params
                         progress:nil
                          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, NSDictionary *responseObject) {

                              NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

                              if (success) {
                                  success(responseObject);
                              }

                          }
                          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                              NSLog(@"getInformationWithParams Error: %@", error);

                              if (failure) {
                                  failure(error);
                              }

                          }];
```

}

previously I did baseURL init

```
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3"];
    self.requestOperationManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
```

and in the end I get request through

```
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"snippet",   @"part",
                     @"true",   @"home",
                      myApiKey, @"key",
                        myAccessToken, @"access_token",
                        nil];

[[SMServerManager sharedManager] getInformationWithParams:params
                                                   method:@"activities"
                                                onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *responseObject) {

                                                }
                                                onFailure:^(NSError *error) {

                                                }];
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

PS: Requests work if they don't need to use acces_token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very stupid mistake. I'm confused in several google accounts and make wrong files for project.